# how can I change an arbitrary portion of my document to monospaced/typewriter font in xetex?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, typewriter

I want to put arbitrary portions of my text into a font that looks like it came out of a 1960s manual typewriter. In particular, each character must occupy a column, identical in width to all other columns. By "arbitrary" I mean a portion that could contain paragraph breaks, not just single paragraphs as with `\texttt{something}`.

This leads to several questions.

1. What is the default font used by xelatex for `\textttt{something}`?
2. How can I use that same font for subsets of my text that include paragraph breaks?
3. In the code below, `\texttt{iiiiiii}` and `\texttt{mmmmmmm}` give identical widths as desired. But the default, supposed "monospace font" of these letters gives emphatically different widths. Why in the world is the default "monospace font" in xetex not monospace?
4. Why does the code below throw the following warning?

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/monofont/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.

[1] (./b.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
hello world

\texttt{iiiiiii}
~\\
\texttt{mmmmmmm}


{
\fontfamily{monofont}\selectfont
This is a separate multi-paragraph block ...

iiiiiii : 7 characters
~\\
mmmmmmm : 7 characters

... inside curly brackets. I want it to 
look like it came out of
a 1960s manual typewriter.}

Now this should be back in main font.
\end{document}
```

My TeX installation is as follows:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.5.8)
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: `\fontfamily{monofont}\selectfont` should be just `\ttfamily`

Comment: just use `\ttfamily` and things will be monospace for the rest of the current group, this is standard latex not xetex specific

Comment: If you want the output to look like a classic IBM typewriter, you might try `\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Scale=MatchUppercase]`. Or your typewriter font of choice. That one is a clone of Courier.

Answer (score 1):

1. The default font for `\texttt` is Computer Modern Typewriter.
2. To use that font you can use `\ttfamily` to select the Computer Modern Typewriter family (Latin Modern Typewriter in XeTeX to allow for enhanced Unicode support).
3. (and 4.) There is no font family called `monofont`. As a result, you got the warning:

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/monofont/m/n' undefined
   (Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 15.
   ```

which indicates that it's substituting Latin Modern *Roman* (LaTeX's default fallback for a missing font).